# What is the difference between // and /// in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, documentation

Stylecop is telling me to use /// instead of // when I´m commenting. What is the semantic difference for those two and when should I use which one?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

// denotes your own personal comments, where /// denote comments that can contain special data, e.g. markup for interpretation by Visual Studio - like:

```
/// <summary>
/// This class does something.
/// </summary>
class Bob {
    ...
}
```

This will tell Visual Studio the summary of the Bob class, and that will then show up in your code completion box.

Answer (score 5):

Found it myself while going through further Stylecop rules:

Use // when commentin

Use /// when documenting for XML documentation headers

Answer (score 1):

The triple slash gives you an automatically generated template with parameters and other features automatically there for you

```
/// <summary>
///  Here is your comment
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">parameter generated automatically</param>
/// <param name="e">as above</param>
void BindableCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
```

This approach means that a tool such as NDoc can then trawl your source to create documentation files automagically. Double slash just doesn't cut it ....

Answer (score 1):

There is no semantic difference, it is just a style of coding or commenting. .NET happens to choose that for comments. It is generally helpful to follow these rules for the automatic code documentation tools like [sandcastle](http://blogs.msdn.com/sandcastle/).

For instance [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) has a completely different commenting style for C++ code. So it is mainly for consistency and standards